# React: getting value from state object by index

Tags: reactjs

I am struggling with the following problem. I've written a react component that inherits the following objects as props

```
assessment: {questions: {question1: 'answer1', 'question2': 'answer2'}

block_index: 1 (could be any number).
```

I want to pass the right question to the 'Quizbuilder' object by using the 'block_index' to fetch the right question.

But for reasons I do not understand

```
this.state.assessment.questions[1]
```

returns a value

while

```
this.state.assessment.questions[this.state.block_index]
```

does not.

They are passed to the 'Quizbuild component' like so

```
<QuizBuilder quiz_object={this.state.assessment.questions[thi.state.block_index]} />
```

I must be missing something, but for the life of me I cannot figure out whats wrong with my code. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `thi` should be `this`.. Not sure if it is a error.. Also your questions is a object and not an array

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(this.state.block_index)` to see if it have any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const assessment =  {questions: {question1: 'answer1', 'question2': 'answer2'}};

console.log(Object.keys(assessment.questions)[0])
```